# google map doesn't show properly in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

The google map shown in my simulator and device is like this,
map view is not there but markers and current point are correct (shown in device)
[image]

However, I have another project which shows the correct map view
[image]

I use the same code for two projects and same SDK

```
mapView_ = [[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - 110)];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView_.delegate = self;
mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
[self.view addSubview:mapView_];
```

---

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.1'
pod 'GoogleMaps'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: This is because you dont have a valid API key in your `AppDelegate.m` 's `didFinishLaunchingWIthOptions` method, make sure you do `[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"YOUR_API_KEY"];` in that method.

Comment: it works now, thank you @ztan